# Using StructuralComparisons class for everything

Tags: c#

I had to compare equality of two two-dimensional arrays. I tried to use `StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(obj1, obj2)` and it works.

So now I wrote this method (in `Helpers` utility class):

```
public static bool Equals<T>(T obj1, T obj2)
{
    return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(obj1, obj2);
}
```

And a question: Which method should I use when I don't know whether Type T is struct (i.e. array) or class? `Object.Equals` or this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

In such situations we can use `StructuralComparisons` comparer because it checks whether first object implements `IStructuralEquatable` and if it really implements, then it uses `IStructuredEquatable.Equals()` method, otherwise it uses `obj1.Equals(obj2)`.

The implementation of this method is listed below

```
public new bool Equals(Object x, Object y) {
    if (x != null) { 

        IStructuralEquatable seObj = x as IStructuralEquatable;

        if (seObj != null){
            return seObj.Equals(y, this);
        }

        if (y != null) {
            return x.Equals(y); 
        } else { 
            return false;
        } 
    }
    if (y != null) return false;
    return true;
}
```